# how this header can be stick?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, antd

this is my ant-list-header elemet css

```
<div class="ant-list-header" style="
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 30px;
"><div class="sc-eDZJSx kXYedM"><strong>Unmapped Rate Plans</strong><strong>See all</strong></div></div>
```

this is my ant-list-items element

`<ul class="ant-list-items"></ul>`

what kind of css will give me ant-list-header sticking

for now
[it is overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDwCT.png)

tried position :sticky and all but not worked

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

its overlapping since your header does not have background

```css
.ant-list-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white; 
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-list-header">
    <div><strong>Unmapped Rate Plans See all</strong></div>
</div>
<ul class="ant-list-items">
    <li>some text</li>
     <li>some text</li>
      <li>some text</li>
       <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
          <li>some text</li>
           <li>some text</li>
     <li>some text</li>
      <li>some text</li>
       <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
          <li>some text</li>
           <li>some text</li>
     <li>some text</li>
      <li>some text</li>
       <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
          <li>some text</li>
           <li>some text</li>
     <li>some text</li>
      <li>some text</li>
       <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
          <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```